# Soma de valores em Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa noite. Tenho que somar as naturezas de acordo com cada setor da empresa, porém não esta indo com count.

SQL:

```
SELECT examefuncionario.exameFunc_Natureza, setor.setor_Nome
FROM `funcionario` 
JOIN examefuncionario ON examefuncionario.exameFunc_CodFuncionario = funcionario.CodFuncionario
JOIN setor on setor.CodSetor = funcionario.funcionario_CodSetor
WHERE `funcionario_CodEmpresa` = '274'
```

[image: Foto do resultado do sql]

Queria que ficasse assim por exemplo:

```
A    D    P   Setor
2    1    5   Portaria/Limpeza
5    2    1   Montagem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `GROUP BY` em conjunto com um `COUNT` condicional.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE examefuncionario.examefunc_natureza WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS A,
       COUNT(CASE examefuncionario.examefunc_natureza WHEN 'D' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS D,
       COUNT(CASE examefuncionario.examefunc_natureza WHEN 'P' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS P, 
       setor.setor_nome 
  FROM `funcionario` 
  JOIN examefuncionario 
    ON examefuncionario.examefunc_codfuncionario = funcionario.codfuncionario 
  JOIN setor ON setor.codsetor = funcionario.funcionario_codsetor 
 WHERE `funcionario_codempresa` = '274'
 GROUP BY setor.setor_nome
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou certinho! Abraços, boa noite